# Create users in OpenAM via REST for non-admin accounts

Tags: rest, identity, openam

Is it possible to create new identities as a non-admin user through OpenAMs REST interface?

The docs suggest it is not possible: http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-rest.html#rest-api-create-identity

If it is not possible, what would be the alternative for a scenario where the user of a mobile app would have the possibility to create a simple 5 digit "pin" password, next to their existing complicated password that contains numbers, letters and special characters.

Our initial idea is to create a new account in OpenAM (hence my question) that uses a new username (their existing username with 'mobile' appended for example) and the new PIN password.

Could we do this using REST or should we create our own webservice and use the OpenAM client SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overloading the password attribute to be used to hold the PIN, you would be better off creating an LDAP PIN attribute.  The chapter on
[Customizing Profile Attributes](http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/dev-guide/index/chap-custom-attr.html) provides instructions on how to add a custom attribute.